# How can I extract usable values from this arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I was given this question and the answers; however I cannot see how any values were calculated from the question to find the final answer

*An arithmetic sequence $v_1, v_2, v_3,$ ... is such that $v_2 = u_2$ and $v_4 = u_4$.
Find the greatest value of N such that $$\sum_{n=1}^N v_n > 0\tag{displayed}$$ 
The answers say to first find $v_2$ ($v_2 = 9$) and $v_4$ ($v_4 = 1$) and work your way from there. How did they arrive at these values in the first place if all im given is V and U without any numerical terms?

A geometric sequence $u_1, u_2, u_3, ...$ has $u_1 = 27$ and an infinite amount of terms.

(a) Find the common ratio of the geometric sequence.
(an earlier part of the question though they look unrelated)

Comment: @daOnlyBG:  I think you changed the meaning of the post in your edit.  It looks to me like "sum to infinity of " meant there was some limit that OP failed to include.  This wording just says the sum is infinite.  David K's interpretation looks good to me, which will have the sum be $40\frac 12$

Comment: Gotcha. The original wording was a bit awkward in the question; I'll make the appropriate correction now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written, one cannot determine $v_2=9,v_4=1$.  Either the problem is a mess or you have missed part of it.

The part you added is crucial, but you have lost the sum at infinity.  That allows us to determine all the $u$s from $s=\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i=u_1\frac 1{1-r}$.  We are given $u_1$, so $s$ will let us determine $r$ and then $u_4=u_1r^3$

Answer (score 1):

If a multiple-part question defines a geometric sequence $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, \ldots$ in one part, and in a *later* part uses the terms $u_2$ and $u_4$ to define something else, then I would assume that the $u_2$ and $u_4$ that occur in the later part of the question are the same $u_2$ and $u_4$ that occur in the earlier part.

The version of this question that I'm looking at now has an incomplete
description of the earlier part of the question, but apparently the
sequence was $u_1 = 27, u_2 = 9, u_3 = 3, u_4 = 1, \ldots .$
Since we are given that $v_2 = u_2$ and we know $u_2 = 9$,
it follows that $v_2 = 9$. For similar reasons we find that $v_4 = 1$.